# What is the difference between t sql collate with AS and AI

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

What is the difference between t sql collate with AS and AI?
Does anybody have a list of collated characters for each?

```
select distinct s1.Field1, s2.Field2
    from s1 inner join s2
        on s1.Field1 collate Latin1_General_CI_AI = s2.Field2 collate Latin1_General_CI_AI

select distinct s1.Field1, s2.Field2
    from s1 inner join s2
        on s1.Field1 collate Latin1_General_CI_AS = s2.Field2 collate Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AI == accent-insensitive
AS == accent-sensitive
```

Info about both collate:

```
Latin1_General_CI_AI    Latin1-General, case-insensitive, accent-insensitive, kanatype-insensitive, width-insensitive
Latin1_General_CI_AS    Latin1-General, case-insensitive, accent-sensitive, kanatype-insensitive, width-insensitive
```

For more info about all collate then

```
SELECT name, description
FROM fn_helpcollations()
```

Please refer [Doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The difference in collation between AI/AS is Accent Sensitive (AS) and Accent Insensitive (AI).

And the CI/CS mean Case Insensitive (CI) and Case Sensitive (CS).